# How can I Present Two Documents Side-By-Side to a Client with One Scrollable View?

Tags: document-management, documentation-viewer

What application could I use to easily display side-by-side pages/documents/columns that scroll in lock-step so a client can easily review two columns of documentation information in parallel?

This needs to run on Mac OS for the client. Windows would be second choice.

Price limit is basically $0.  And prefer to stay with common software since hopefully it's something the client will already have access to on Mac OS.

My best idea so far is to put alternating pages in a PDF and have the client use the Acrobat Reader setting to view two pages side-by-side.  This results in odd numbers on the left and even numbers on the right.  Another possibility is to go to a landscape page layout and make two columns and generate a PDF from that.

**If you want detailed background, here it is:**
I have a client who is Math savvy, but not as computer programming savvy.  I have some specific math-intense computer code that I want to show to the client so he can verify it is correct for his purposes.  But to simplify the presentation, I'd like to show the original code side-by-side with pseudo-code to make it easier for him to follow the progression of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

github.com has a 'compare changes' function which might help you. In the example in this image, I entered pseudo code for the 2d distance calculation and them compared it to the final implementation.

[image]

Comment: That is a very interesting idea John.  I'm actually using GitHub on the project, so that might work as an elegant solution.